# Erro : TemplateNotFound Pendente

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Estou querendo criar uma aplicação básica, porem não estou conseguindo renderizar o templete na aplicação 
Estrutura do projeto

```
├── Project
│   ├── Controllers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── Models
│   │   └── Conexao
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── View
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── View_index_page.py
│       └── View_index_page.pyc
├── run.py
└── run.pyc
```

Run.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from Project.View.View_index_page import simple_page


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(simple_page)  
app.run(debug=True)
```

view.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template,url_for


simple_page = 
Blueprint('simple_page',__name__,template_folder='templates')

@simple_page.route('/')
    def show():
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: O diretório com os templates tá salvo exatamente com o nome templates? Se possível adiciona a estrutura do seu projeto.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Só um momento

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Pronto!

Comment: ótimo! Tô sem tempo pra escrever uma resposta, mas dá uma olhada na doc do Blueprints com Flask (especialmente na sessão sobre Templates), lá tem a estrutura exata dos diretórios, e não vai precisar nem usar o `template_folder`: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#templates

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim fiz igual a estrutura e mesmo assim emite uma mensagem de template NotFound

Comment: outra coisa - a presença dos arquivos ".pyc" indica que você está usando Python 2.7 - não tem por qu enão usar Python 3.7 para um projeto novo em Flask - vocẽ está jogando fora literalmente 10 anos de evolução da linguagem, além de várias ferramentas essenciais que nem suportam mais Python 2.

Comment: nao estou entendo, vc está adicionado um blueprint do arquivo View_index_page, porem o blueprint está no arquivo view.py o codigo do view.py é o mesmo do View_index_page ?

Comment: a minha lógica estava meio confusa, acabei vendo que nao estava registrando de maneira correta o blueprint, arrumei e funcionou

Comment: @jsbueno Não sei o motivo de estar criando esse "pyc" sendo que estou utilizando o 3.7 nao sei se é por causa do vs code

Comment: O 3.7 cria aquivos ".pyc"  - mas eles devem ficar dentro de uma pasta "__pycache__" em cada pasta aí. O ".pyc" jogado no meio do caminho indica que uma versão antiga de Python está lendo o arquivo . Pra código simples, python 2 não vai encontrar erro de sintaxe-  pode ser sim alguma ferramenta do vscode usando Python 2.